# detectar ultima celda vacía, Python Excel

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Buen dia, Estoy intentando detectar la ultima celda vacía de una fila en Excel.
Por ejemplo.

A1 Hola

A2 Hol2

A3 Vacio

Entonces me devolvería A3 Como vacio.

Si con esto escribo dentro de celdas.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

    filesheet = 'prueba.xlsx'
    wb = load_workbook(filesheet)
    sheet = wb.active
    sheet['A1']= 123
    sheet['A2']= 145
    sheet['A3']= 179
    wb.save(filesheet)
```

Y con esto puedo leer.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

path = 'prueba.xlsx'
wb = load_workbook(filename = path)
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Hoja1')
sheet_ranges = wb.active
num1 = sheet_ranges['A1'].value
num2 = sheet_ranges['A2'].value
num3 = sheet_ranges['A3'].value
```

Como podría detectar la ultima celda vacía después de la celda que lleva algo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes obtener la primera celda vacia con la ayuda de
[*Worksheet.calculate_dimension*](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html?highlight=calculate_dimension#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.calculate_dimension).

Si tenemos la siguiente hoja de trabajo:

```
+---+-----+-----+
|   |  A  |  B  |
+---+-----+-----+
| 1 | 123 | 123 |
+---+-----+-----+
| 2 | 123 | 123 |
+---+-----+-----+
| 3 | 123 | 123 |
+---+-----+-----+
```

*calculate_dimension* devuelve el rango mínimo que encierra a los datos, por
ejemplo:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("prueba.xlsx")
print(wb.active.calculate_dimension()) # A1:B3
```

Entonces se puede obtener la primera celda vacia combinando la primera columna
(A) con la siguiente de la ultima fila (4), usando regex para separar las
dimensiones:

```
import re

def primera_celda_vacia(dimensiones):
    columna, fila = re.search(r"([A-Z]+)\d+:[A-Z]+(\d+)", dimensiones).groups()
    return f"{columna}{int(fila)+1}"

# A4 Vacío
print(f"{primera_celda_vacia(wb.active.calculate_dimension())} Vacío")
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, Entiendo tu solucion. Per como haria para que me devuelva otras filas como B4 o C4 ? Por separado cada uno

Comment: @RicharlyxD ¿Te refieres a las otras celdas de la misma fila? Eso es un poco más complicado, se me ocurre iterar por las letras mayusculas de `string.ascii_uppercase` y a cada letra concatenarle el numero de fila (en este caso 4). Pregunta aparte, tal vez el objetivo es agregar una fila pero sin saber cual es la ultima fila?

Comment: Entiendo, Bueno en mi proyecto solo utilizo una sola fila, Asi que solo reemplaze las demas con la letra `"B"+int(fila)`, Pero tengo un problema. Al llegar a las celda Numero 10, La siguiente fila la da como `A1`, deberia ser como `A11`

Comment: Ahh, ya se qué pasa, la expresión regular está mal, la sequencia `\w` empareja con caracteres alfanumericos y yo solo quería que lo haga con letras mayusculas. Ahí la actualicé en la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

```
sheet.max_row                   # 3 es la última fila
```

---

Otra forma:

```
sheet[sheet.calculate_dimension().split(':')[-1]].row
```

Por pasos:

1. sheet.calculate_dimension() # obtienes un string de la forma "A1:B3"
2. "A1:B3".split(':')[-1]      # 'B3'
3. sheet['B3'].row             # 3  es la última fila